# Login to remote SSL site with PHP Curl fails

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I got stuck trying to figure out why I can't access one specific SSL protected site, https://www.stockpair.com, using PHP Curl. The problem is that I just don't get any output at all.
I used similar coding several times before but for this site it just doesn't work. 
I'm using a simple php-curl-class (https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) in the below code but also tried without and experienced the same problem.

**login.php**

```
include_once('functions/curl.class.php');

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$curl->post('https://www.stockpair.com/session/authenticate?json', array(
    'email' => 'usermail',
    'password' => 'pass',
));

echo $curl->response;

?>
```

**Edit**
I just used the CLI version of Curl:

> curl -k http s://stockpair.com

and got the following back:

> curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.stockpair.com:443

Could it be related?

Comment: Can you post the response headers ?

Comment: Since `$curl->response_headers` is empty as well, I'm afraid there is no response.

Comment: Try setting CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 3 using `$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);`

Comment: Still no output with CURLOPT_SSLVERSION set to 3.

Comment: I got the same error and I used the `--sslv3` option in curl CLI version to get the response. That is why I asked you to set the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 3.

Comment: That's true, on CLI the `--sslv3` option is working perfectly well. Looks like it is being ignored by PHP. I'll try to option without the curl class.

Comment: Thanks man, you put me on the right track!
It was indeed related to the SSLV3 option, but the class I was using didn't recognized that option. Now I updated php-curl-class to the latest version and this issue is fixed. It's working now!

Comment: Cool. Happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying doing a var_dump on $curl->post()

```
var_dump($curl->post());
```

You might see some information about whether or not it worked or what the error messages associated with curl->post().

Comment: So I just wrapped `var_dump` around my above post request resulting in `var_dump($curl>post('https://www.stockpair.com/session/authenticate?json', array('email' => 'usermail','password' => 'pass')));` but unfortunately the response is `NULL`.

Comment: It could be that no curl session has been started. Maybe a curl_init() might help.
http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but actually the `$curl = new Curl();` is supposed to do the init. Weird thing is that I'm using exactly the same code on other (SSL) sites and it's working well.